# Quartz Corn Scheduler fails on weekends C#

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz Schedular with c#.
I wish to run it at 12:05 AM **everyday**
It works great on weekdays however never run on Saturday and Sunday.

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .ForJob(job)
            .WithIdentity("myTrigger")
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("0 05 0 * * ?"))
            .Build();
```

And if I try to get next trigger after Friday, it shows correct date that is saturday's.

Comment: Hello sir, are you sure that it does not fire? aren't you getting any exception at the job execution?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the logs, usually it writes "batch acquisition of 1 triggers" when it fires. and on weekends it wrote "batch acquisition of 0 triggers"  Any error is expected here?

Comment: Hi again! I investigated more on this and found it's not the weekends only but random! I think it's might be about thread priority. I tried  withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow() but not sure how it actually works and so. Now I left with the unpredictable behaviour of the scheduler. Please suggest